# 8085 Microprocessor - Assembly DB Directive

Tags: assembly, microprocessors, 8085

I am having a problem with the following assembly code.

```
PROGX: MVI C, 10h
LOOP1: CALL SHOWX
DATAX: DB 80h, 01h, 40h, 02h
       DB 20h, 04h, 10h, 08h
       DB 08h, 10h, 04h, 20h
       DB 02h, 40h, 01h, 80h
       DB 02h, 40h, 04h, 20h
       DB 08h, 10h, 10h, 08h
       DB 20h, 04h, 40h, 02h
DCR C
JNZ LOOP1
ENDX: HLT

SHOWX: XTHL
MVI B, 0Eh
LOOP2: MOV A, M
OUT 3Eh
INX H
MOV A, M
OUT 3Fh
INX H
DCR B
JNZ LOOP2
CALL D500M ; Delay 500 msec.
XTHL
RET
```

After the execution of ShowX in the 1st Loop of Loop1 there is this DATAX that is using the DB Directive to reserve memory.

Can anyone help me understand which will be the starting Memory address where its DB command will start allocating the Bytes in the Memory?

For example below code will start allocating in Address C100H due to the ORG command. So 20h will be stored in C100h and 10h in C100h + 1

```
ORG C100h
DB 20h,10h
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Do not place data in the middle of code. The address will be whatever the current address is, which we don't know because there is no `ORG` (but you may have some default).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Moreover since this is an exercise that i need to execute and get the result for some leds , if i set a default address with ORG in the start then the DB will start from that address?